# Show Gaps in Data for ListLinePlot3D

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics, graphics3d, missing

For some reason, showing gaps in data is easier with `ListLinePlot` than with the closely related `ListLinePlot3D`. For example, `Null` can be used to show gaps in data as below in the orange plot.

```
ListLinePlot[{{1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4}, {4, 1, 0, 1, Null, Null, 1, 2}},
 Mesh -> Full, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

[image: ListLinePlot1]

However, this does not work correctly with `ListLinePlot3D`, whereby `Null` is interpreted as interpolation between the elements it lies between, as illustrated below.

```
ListLinePlot3D[{{1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4}, {4, 1, 0, 1, Null, Null, 1, 2}}, 
Mesh -> Full, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

[image: ListLinePlot3D1]

Replacing `Null` with `Nothing` or `Sequence[]` doesn't work for the obvious reasons, and using `Indeterminate`, using `Missing[]`, and using some non-numeric element like an empty string all give the same result `Null` gives.*

***How can I accurately represent gaps in data the way `ListLinePlot` does but with `ListLinePlot3D`?*** The data sets I am dealing with are quite large with many "gaps", so I'd like the solution to scale well and have good performance.

---

*In the case of `Missing[]`, it seems like this is an oversight, as the following are stated and demonstrated in the documentation for `ListLinePlot`: "Plotting functions automatically omit Missing objects when plotting data" and "Visualization typically automatically filters out Missing elements". I consider `ListLinePlot3D` a "plotting function" and "visualization", but it does not have the behavior specified.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4}, {4, 1, 0, 1, Null, Null, 1, 2}};

Graphics3D[{Thick, 
  MapIndexed[({d, i} |-> {ColorData[97][First[i]], 
      Line@SequenceSplit[
        MapIndexed[{First[#2], First[i], #1} &, d], {{_, _, Null}}]}),
    data]}, Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.4`}]

ListLinePlot3D[data, Mesh -> Full]
```

[image]